# C# Send Bytes Not Working

Tags: c#, sockets, arrays, send

i just wanted to ask why when i try to send a byte , its not sent at all , i've made a simple program and dont know why its now working (send property in both client and Server)
here is my Server Side Code

```
    public void ServerStartReceiving()
    {
        sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        sck.Bind(new IPEndPoint(0, 1980));
        sck.Listen(0);
        acc = sck.Accept();
        sck.Close();
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                byte[] sizeBuff = new byte[4];
                acc.Receive(sizeBuff, 0, sizeBuff.Length, 0);
                int size = BitConverter.ToInt32(sizeBuff, 0);
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                while (size > 0)
                {
                    byte[] buffer;
                    lblStatus.Text = "Receiveing Text....";
                    if (size < acc.ReceiveBufferSize)
                    {
                        buffer = new byte[size];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        buffer = new byte[acc.ReceiveBufferSize];
                    }
                    int rec = acc.Receive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, 0);
                    size -= rec;
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                }
                ms.Close();
                byte[] data = ms.ToArray();
                ms.Dispose();





                while (true == true)
                {
                    byte[] sizelang = new byte[4];
                    acc.Receive(sizelang, 0, sizelang.Length, 0);
                    lblStatus.Text = "Receiving Language Data....";
                    int sizela = BitConverter.ToInt32(sizelang, 0);
                    MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream();
                    while (sizela > 0)
                    {
                        byte[] lang;

                        if (sizela < acc.ReceiveBufferSize)
                        {
                            lang = new byte[sizela];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lang = new byte[acc.ReceiveBufferSize];
                        }
                        int rec = acc.Receive(lang, 0, lang.Length, 0);
                        sizela -= rec;
                        ms1.Write(lang, 0, lang.Length);
                    }
                    ms1.Close();
                    byte[] datalang = ms1.ToArray();
                    ms1.Dispose();

                    Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                        {
                            string lang = Encoding.Default.GetString(datalang);
                            string datall = Encoding.Default.GetString(data);
                            Translator t = new Translator();
                            t.SourceLanguage = lang;
                            t.SourceText = datall;
                            t.TargetLanguage = ReadLangRead();
                            lblStatus.Text = "Translating...";
                            t.Translate();
                            txtLog.Text += System.Environment.NewLine + "Other Person: " + t.Translation;
                        });
                }

            }
        }).Start();
    }

    public void ServerSend(byte[] message,string lang)
    {
        message = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(txtMessage.Text);
        sck.Send(BitConverter.GetBytes(message.Length),0,4,0);
        sck.Send(message);
        //--------------------------------------------
        byte[] langbyte;
        langbyte = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(lang);
        sck.Send(BitConverter.GetBytes(langbyte.Length),0,4,0);
        sck.Send(langbyte);
    }
```

And the Client Side Code

```
 public void ClientSend(byte[] message, string lang)
    {
        message = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(txtMessage.Text);
        sck.Send(BitConverter.GetBytes(message.Length), 0, 4, 0);
        sck.Send(message);
        //--------------------------------------------
        byte[] langbyte;
        langbyte = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(lang);
        sck.Send(BitConverter.GetBytes(langbyte.Length), 0, 4, 0);
        sck.Send(langbyte);
    }
    public void ClientStartReceiving()
    {
        MemoryStream lgst = new MemoryStream();
        MemoryStream bfst = new MemoryStream();
        new Thread(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    byte[] bufferSize = new byte[4];
                    byte[] buffer;
                    byte[] langsize = new byte[4];
                    byte[] lang;
                    NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(sck);
                    ns.Read(bufferSize, 0, bufferSize.Length);
                    int datasize = (BitConverter.ToInt32(bufferSize, 0));

                    buffer = new byte[datasize];
                    int read = 0;
                    while (read != buffer.Length)
                    {
                        read += ns.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    }

                    bfst.Write(buffer,0,buffer.Length);


                    //------------------------------------
                    ns.Read(langsize, 0, langsize.Length);

                    int langsizeint = (BitConverter.ToInt32(langsize, 0));
                    lang = new byte[langsizeint];
                    int read1 = 0;
                    while (read1 != lang.Length)
                    {
                        read1 += ns.Read(lang, 0, lang.Length);
                    }

                    lgst.Write(lang, 0, lang.Length);
                    lgst.Close();
                    bfst.Close();
                    byte[] langau = lgst.ToArray();
                    byte[] dataau = bfst.ToArray();
                    lgst.Dispose();
                    bfst.Dispose();

                    Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {
                        string langst = Encoding.Default.GetString(langau);
                        string datall = Encoding.Default.GetString(dataau);
                        Translator t = new Translator();
                        t.SourceLanguage = langst;
                        t.SourceText = datall;
                        t.TargetLanguage = ReadLangRead();
                        lblStatus.Text = "Translating...";
                        t.Translate();
                        txtLog.Text +=System.Environment.NewLine +"Other Person: "+ t.Translation;
                    });
                }
            }).Start();
    }

    public void ClientConnect()
    {

        Select_Partnener Form = new Select_Partnener();
        sck.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(Form.IP),1980));

    }
```

Comment: "it's not working" is not a helpful description of the problem. What did you expect? What actually happened?

Comment: Next time please not just copy/paste code but also add some effort to format it properly.

Comment: `while (true == true)` makes me a sad panda :*(

Answer (score 1):

Here's the most obvious bug:

```
                while (read != buffer.Length)
                {
                    read += ns.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                }
```

1) You don't want to read into `buffer` if you've already read some bytes. You need to read into the right part of the buffer.

2) You don't want to read `buffer.Length` bytes. You want to read however many bytes you haven't read yet.

Comment: i dont understand can you give me an example??

Comment: Say `buffer.Length` is 8. That means you want to read 8 bytes. If your first call to `ns.Read` reads 4 bytes, you still try to read 8 bytes and you try to read on top of the 4 bytes you already read. The `while` loop makes no sense.

Comment: The easiest way is to fix the `while` loop. Only try to read the number of bytes remaining. And read into a new buffer which you append onto the buffer that will contain the final results.

Comment: No. While the total number of bytes read is fewer than the total number of bytes you need to read.

Comment: the problem is how can i know the total numbers of bytes i need

Comment: That's up to you. You can have the other side send the number of bytes needed prior to the data if you want.

Comment: ok, another thing , when i try to wait for the client the window comes laaggy and i cant control anything with it , how can i fix this??

Comment: Either don't wait for the client and instead use some kind of asynchronous I/O or wait for the client in a thread other than the one that runs your GUI.